# Is there any VGA graphics mode which gives 40x25 text?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, vga

I am making a Tic Tac Toe game using assembly language, which includes (it should) print the winner (Player 1 or Player 2). I have used VGA 16 color graphics mode. The problem I am facing is, I want to print the winner's identity in a bigger (40x25 chars) font, and also without wiping out the game. When I write

```
mov ah, 0h
mov al, 1h
int 10h
```

The entire game screen wipes out (which should happen for `mov ah, 0h` instruction). So I removed `mov ah, 0h` instruction. As a result, the game itself did not go away, but the character mode remains in 80x60 chars mode, so the texts are printed small.

Comment: How would you even keep the existing text if you change the mode? And you can't just call ints with random values and expect it to do something.

Comment: You could look at the [standard resource of Interrupt Tables](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm) to find the one fitting your needs.

Comment: Yes: BIOS `int 10h` function `00h` shows grahics modes 04h, 05h, 09h, 0Dh, 13h support 40x25 text.

Comment: Maybe use ASCII-art to draw the characters of the winner's name using multiple screen characters for each actual letter.

Comment: Also, IDK why people are down-voting this but up-voting dumber newbie-questions.  Maybe just because this one happens not to have a good or easy answer?  Obviously the attempted solution (`int 21h` with random garbage in `ah`) can't possibly work, and shows a complete failure to understand what's going on, but that doesn't stop other questions from getting upvoted.  I think this is actually better than most newbie questions, since a debugger + google wouldn't solve it.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to have different font-sizes on screen at once in text-mode.  But you could use ASCII-art to draw the characters of the winner's name using multiple screen characters for each actual letter.  Or use VGA graphics mode and draw everything.

Comment: hey, it's graphics mode. Find out where the characters bitmaps are (or use your own bitmaps) and paint it yourself, using 4 pixels ( 2 in both x and y direction) for each pixel<br>
if you cannot find the bitmaps, you could use a loop to write each character you need in the top-left corner, and read out the pixels from there